# Magento : How to send contact form email with attachment in magento?

Tags: magento, email-attachments, zend-mail

Is there any default functionality in Magento for a simple contact form that needs to send a file attachment? Or do I need to customise it with Zend's mail function? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### add file button in the contact form

To avoid editing the phtml file, I like to use events:

1. create observer in config.xml:

   ```
   <events>
       <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
           <observers>
               <add_file_boton>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>contactattachment/observer</class>
                   <method>addFileBoton</method>
               </add_file_boton>
           </observers>
       </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
   </events>
   ```
2. the observer:

   ```
   class Osdave_ContactAttachment_Model_Observer
   {
       public function addFileBoton($observer)
       {
           $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
           $nameInLayout = $block->getNameInLayout();

           if ($nameInLayout == 'contactForm') {
               $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
               $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('contactattachment/field');
               $block->setPassingTransport($transport['html']);
               $block->setTemplate('contactattachment/field.phtml')
                       ->toHtml();
           }
           return $this;
       }
   }
   ```
3. the block class (that you've just instanciated in the observer):

   ```
   class Osdave_ContactAttachment_Block_Field extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
   {
       private $_passedTransportHtml;

       /**
        * adding file select field to contact-form
        * @param type $transport
        */
       public function setPassingTransport($transport)
       {
           $this->_passedTransportHtml = $transport;
       }

       public function getPassedTransport()
       {
           return $this->_passedTransportHtml;
       }
   }
   ```
4. the .phtml file, where you add the enctype attribute to the form and add the file input:

   ```
   <?php
   $originalForm = $this->getPassedTransport();
   $originalForm = str_replace('action', 'enctype="multipart/form-data" action', $originalForm);
   $lastListItem = strrpos($originalForm, '</li>') + 5;
   echo substr($originalForm, 0, $lastListItem);
   ?>
   <li>
       <label for="attachment"><?php echo $this->__('Select an attachment:') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
           <input type="file" class="input-text" id="attachment" name="attachment" />
       </div>
   </li>
   <?php
   echo substr($originalForm, $lastListItem);
   ?>
   ```

   ### procesing the attachment

you need to rewrite Magento's Contacts IndexController to upload the file where you want to and add the link in the email.

- config.xml:

  ```
      <global>
          ...
          <rewrite>
              <osdave_contactattachment_contact_index>
                  <from><![CDATA[#^/contacts/index/#]]></from>
                  <to>/contactattachment/contacts_index/</to>
              </osdave_contactattachment_contact_index>
          </rewrite>
          ...
      </global>

      <frontend>
          ...
          <routers>
              <contactattachment>
                  <use>standard</use>
                  <args>
                      <module>Osdave_ContactAttachment</module>
                      <frontName>contactattachment</frontName>
                  </args>
              </contactattachment>
          </routers>
          ...
      </frontend>
  ```
- the controller:

  ```
  <?php

  /**
   * IndexController
   *
   * @author david
   */

  require_once 'Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php';
  class Osdave_ContactAttachment_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
  {
      public function postAction()
      {
          $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
          if ( $post ) {
              $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
              /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
              $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
              try {
                  $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                  $postObject->setData($post);

                  $error = false;

                  if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                      $error = true;
                  }

                  if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                      $error = true;
                  }

                  if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                      $error = true;
                  }

                  if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                      $error = true;
                  }

                  if ($error) {
                      throw new Exception();
                  }

                  //upload attachment
                  try {
                      $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('attachment');
                      $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                      $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                      $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                      $result = $uploader->save(
                          Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contact_attachments' . DS
                      );
                      $fileUrl = str_replace(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS, Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), $result['path']);
                  } catch (Exception $e) {
                      Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contactattachment')->__('There has been a problem with the file upload'));
                      $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                      return;
                  }

                  $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                  /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                  $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                      ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                      ->sendTransactional(
                          Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                          Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                          Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                          null,
                          array('data' => $postObject)
                      );

                  if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                      throw new Exception();
                  }

                  $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                  $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                  return;
              } catch (Exception $e) {
                  $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                  $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                  return;
              }

          } else {
              $this->_redirect('*/*/');
          }
      }
  }
  ```

in the controller you need to add the `$fileUrl` into the email template, and on your email template file you need to echo it.
I think this is the whole thing, let me know if you're having troubles with that.
cheers

Comment: That is a truly inspiring answer. 'To avoid editing the phtml' opens up a whole new area of how-to-develop for me. As it happens my contacts form is a long way past base theme so I did not take that direction - but I wish more extension developers did! I also think that the link to the file makes a lot more sense than using attachments, so I took that approach. You will be glad to know that I have my upload working swimmingly. Thanks again for the tips and solution.

Comment: @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ glad I could help. The "avoid edit phtml" part comes from a post @ inchoo, I've just broad it a bit to use block and phtml files. The link Vs attachment is because of the comment you left for Vincent, where you came up with that solution. ps: how do you write your nick? ;)

Comment: I saw someone else's nickname upside down and I thought I would try the same. Looks fine on Ubuntu (what I use) but I think it renders funny on normal PC's. I have not been hampered by people not being able to type it. I might take up using my cat's name - 'Theodore' - he has quite a large online presence these days but he doesn't seem to show much enthusiasm for EAV, MVC, Prototype.js or anything else Magento. Anyway, good luck with your Magento projects and I look forward to the day I can help you out with something!

Answer (score 2):

For adding an attachment to an email you will need to use the following Zend_Mail function:

```
public function createAttachment($body,
                                 $mimeType    = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                                 $disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                                 $encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                                 $filename    = null)
{
```

Here is an example to use it with Magento, for attaching a pdf file to the email:

```
$myEmail = new new Zend_Mail('utf-8'); //see app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php - getMail()
$myEmail->createAttachment($file,'application/pdf',Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,$name.'.pdf');
```

You can use this extension for inspiration: [Fooman Email Attachments](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-email-attachments.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link - I lost my attachment ability when my own code died after 1.4 - you have saved me a re-write (thanks to Fooman too!). Any chance you can also lend me some help on how I get the box on the page? I know I can have just-a-box but I haven't done it yet!

Comment: You mean the file upload input?

Comment: [Add fields to contact form](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/contacts/add_fields_to_contact_form) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about default functionality but this may help - http://ecommercesoftwaresolutionsonline.com/magento-enquiry-feedback-form-with-attachment-extension.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am keen to do it myself though as I have lots of other things on the page that are not going to be able to achieve with any off-the-shelf contact form. Ideally I want uploads to go to /media/whatever with that directory having a password protected .htaccess and a link to the uploaded file being sent that way to 'admin'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120406073139/http://keefir.ee/2011/12/02/zend-mail-easy-e-mailing-with-attachments) describing how easily you can send email with attachments:

Answer (score 0):

Not Magento related, but I use PHP's SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/):

```
require_once('../lib/swiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php');

...


$body="Dear $fname,\n\nPlease find attached, an invoice for the period $startDate - $endDate\n\nBest regards,\n\nMr X";

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject goes here')
    ->setFrom(array($email => "no-reply@mydomain.com"))
    ->setTo(array($email => "$fname $lname"))
    ->setBody($body);
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath("../../invoices_unpaid/$id.pdf"));

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```